# Laravel 5 updateOrCreate (or Delete)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a setup where, I have a user_roles table.

Then the administrator, will be able to update these, by adding new role, updating the name of an old role, and lastly delete.

```
------------------
| id | user_role |
| 1  | admin     |
| 2  | role 1    |
| 3  | role 3    |
------------------
```

I tried to use this block of code to update, add, delete the roles

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $roles = Model::all();
    foreach($roles as $role){
        $role->delete();  
    }

    foreach($request->role as $role){
        $role = new Model;
        $role->user_role = $role;
        $role->save();
    }
}
```

But in the users table, I have a user_role column that references to the id of the user_roles table, so whenever I use the above code, all rows will be deleted, then a new id will be created for the new rows inserted. So, when I go back to the list of users, their user_role column will return null, because each user has a non-existing user_role id.

Using `updateOrCreate` kind of solves my problem, when it comes to updating old row/s or creating new row/s but the problem is, deleting rows. It can't delete rows.

I need to delete the rows that are existing in the database, and missing in the request.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this case using the **id** approach proposed by maslauskast @ https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/updateorcreate-rows-from-a-csv-or-delete-if-not-on-the-csv?page=0

In your case a solution* will be

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){

    $usersRoleToDelete = Model::all()->pluck('id', 'id');

    foreach($request->role as $role) {
       $createdOrUpdated = Model::createOrUpdate(['user_role' => $role]);

       if (!empty($usersRoleToDelete[$createdOrUpdated->id])) {
           unset($usersRoleToDelete[$createdOrUpdated->id]);
       }
    }

    if (count($usersRoleToDelete)) {
        Model::whereRaw(sprintf('id IN (%s)', implode(',', $usersRoleToDelete)))->delete();

        /* Alternatively you could use 
        *     Model::whereIn('id', $usersRoleToDelete)->delete();
        *  if the amount of ids is smaller than the maximum PDO arguments allowed
        */
    }

}
```

- Please note that I have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

this is my working updateOrCreate method based on Adrian answer in Laravel 5.3

```
 public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $et=Model::find($id);
    //update some parent table field's (if you want)

    $et['type']=$request['type'];
    $et['sum'] =preg_replace('/[^0-9]/s', '', $request['sum']); //for remove thousand separtor
    $et->save();

    $et_det=$et->et_dets()
        ->pluck('id','id'); // one-to-many relation
    for ($i=0;$i<count($request['det_id']);$i++)
    {//some matching condition
        $createdOrUpdated = Model_dets::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'parent_id'=>$id,
                'total'=>$request['total'][$i]
            ],
            [
                'columnA' => $request['columnA'][$i],
                'ColumnB' => $request['ColumnB'][$i])
            ]);

        if (!empty($et_det[$createdOrUpdated->id])) {
            unset($et_det[$createdOrUpdated->id]);
        }

    }

    if (count($et_det)) {
        Model_det::whereIn('id', $et_det)->delete();

    }

    return Redirect::to('index')->with('alert-success','Update successfully');
}
```